# Interfacing 45DB161 data flash with 89LP4052 controller

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, spi, flash-memory

I am trying to interface the data flash with 89lp 4052 controller. 
Crysal used 11.0592 mhz.
This controller has built in spi bus. 
I tried all combinations of CPHA AND CPOL. Tried mode 0 as well as mode 3. Not able to read staus register. 
Some times it happens that it reads the register but sometimes it  just ff code out from flash.

my code is as follows.

```
                        CLR     SCLK
        CLR     CS
        LCALL       DELAY2
```

;;==============================================================================

WRITE_FLASH:        MOV     20H,#0D7H       ;COMMAND
            LCALL       SEND_CLOCK_ONE
            LCALL       READ_FLASH
            CLR     SCON.1
            MOV     A,21H
            MOV     SBUF,A
            JNB     SCON.1,$
            CLR     SCON.1
;;=======================================================================
            SETB        CS
            CLR     SCLK
            LCALL       DELAY2
            CLR     CS          ;SELECTED AGAIN
            MOV     20H,#84H
            LCALL       SEND_CLOCK
            MOV     20H,#00H
            LCALL       SEND_CLOCK
            MOV     20H,#00H
            LCALL       SEND_CLOCK
            MOV     20H,#00H
            LCALL       SEND_CLOCK
            MOV     20H,#33H
            LCALL       SEND_CLOCK
            LCALL       DELAY2
            SETB        CS
            LCALL       DELAY2
            CLR     SCLK
            CLR     CS          ;SELECTED AGAIN
            MOV     20H,#0D4H
            LCALL       SEND_CLOCK
            MOV     20H,#00H
            LCALL       SEND_CLOCK
            MOV     20H,#00H
            LCALL       SEND_CLOCK
            MOV     20H,#00H
            LCALL       SEND_CLOCK
            MOV     20H,#00H
            LCALL       SEND_CLOCK_ONE

```
        LCALL       READ_FLASH
        CLR     SCON.1
        MOV     A,21H
        MOV     SBUF,A
        JNB     SCON.1,$
        CLR     SCON.1
        SETB        CS
        SETB        SCLK
        LCALL       DELAY2

        LJMP        REP
```

;;=======================================================================
SEND_CLOCK_ONE:     MOV     C,07H           ;MSB
            MOV     DOUT,C
            LCALL       PULSE_SEND
            MOV     C,06H
            MOV     DOUT,C
            LCALL       PULSE_SEND
            MOV     C,05H
            MOV     DOUT,C
            LCALL       PULSE_SEND
            MOV     C,04H
            MOV     DOUT,C
            LCALL       PULSE_SEND
            MOV     C,03H
            MOV     DOUT,C
            LCALL       PULSE_SEND
            MOV     C,02H
            MOV     DOUT,C
            LCALL       PULSE_SEND
            MOV     C,01H
            MOV     DOUT,C
            LCALL       PULSE_SEND
            MOV     C,00H
            MOV     DOUT,C
            LCALL       PULSE_SEND_LAST
            RET
;;===========================================================================
READ_FLASH:     LCALL       PULSE_SEND                          MOV     C,DIN
            MOV     0FH,C
            LCALL       PULSE_SEND
            MOV     C,DIN
            MOV     0EH,C
            LCALL       PULSE_SEND
            MOV     C,DIN
            MOV     0DH,C
            LCALL       PULSE_SEND
            MOV     C,DIN
            MOV     0CH,C
            LCALL       PULSE_SEND
            MOV     C,DIN
            MOV     0BH,C
            LCALL       PULSE_SEND
            MOV     C,DIN
            MOV     0AH,C
            LCALL       PULSE_SEND
            MOV     C,DIN
            MOV     09H,C
            LCALL       PULSE_SEND
            MOV     C,DIN
            MOV     08H,C
            LCALL       PULSE_SEND
            RET
;;=======================================================================
SEND_CLOCK:     MOV     C,07H           ;MSB
            MOV     DOUT,C
            LCALL       PULSE_SEND
            MOV     C,06H
            MOV     DOUT,C
            LCALL       PULSE_SEND
            MOV     C,05H
            MOV     DOUT,C
            LCALL       PULSE_SEND
            MOV     C,04H
            MOV     DOUT,C
            LCALL       PULSE_SEND
            MOV     C,03H
            MOV     DOUT,C
            LCALL       PULSE_SEND
            MOV     C,02H
            MOV     DOUT,C
            LCALL       PULSE_SEND
            MOV     C,01H
            MOV     DOUT,C
            LCALL       PULSE_SEND
            MOV     C,00H
            MOV     DOUT,C
            LCALL       PULSE_SEND
            RET

;;===========================================================================
DELAY2:         mov         56H,#0FFH
            DJNZ            56H,$
            mov         56H,#0FFH
            DJNZ            56H,$
            RET
;;===================================================================
PULSE_SEND:     SETB        SCLK
            LCALL       DELAY2
            CLR     SCLK
            LCALL       DELAY2
            RET
;;===================================================
PULSE_SEND_LAST:    SETB        SCLK
            LCALL       DELAY2
            RET
;;===================================================== 
PULSE_READ_FIRST:   CLR     SCLK
            LCALL       DELAY2
            SETB        SCLK
            LCALL       DELAY2
            RET
;;===========================================================

END

Comment: Do not post questions ALL IN CAPS - it is considered rude.

Comment: Also, please think when tagging - the "flash" tag has nothing to do with flash memory.

Comment: Can you show us a code snippet of what you've got at the moment? Perhaps that would help in a diagnosis.

Comment: sorry, I intent to show that how much problem I am having.

Answer (score 2):

Bring out your oscope, look at the SPI bus (the clk signal and the DO from your controller).  Your flash datasheet has a timing diagram that shows how the data should be clocked in and out (on the edge or at the mid-point of each clock cycle), on what edge, and where the bus should idle.

Then tweek the settings on your controller till what you see out of your controller matches what you see on your flash datasheet.

Finally, read the flash datasheet carefully, it probably has something like it expects data in 8 bit chunks or 24 bit chunks before the CS (chip select) pin is raised to end and latch in the data.  Make sure you do that, only when your flash expects it.

Then, it will work.  :-) good luck.

Comment: In addition to the datasheets read any errata for the devices. I got bit last year on a part where some SPI signals were out of phase for one clock if the clock rate divisor had its low bit set.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar symptom when I was coding for a similar Flash chip.

My problem was that there were other Chip Select lines to other chips (RTC, UART, etc) that I did not initialize, so they defaulted to low.  The low Chip Select allows those chips to drive the MISO (master in, slave out) data line so that the microcontroller couldn't read anything.